# How do I get part of a string?

Tags: php, string

I have a string,

```
$str = "Request to recharge SH 20 to 7567674553 is successful. Balance SH 500";
```

I would want to search through and get the **20** alone from this string.

I tried working with **strrchr()** and **substr()** Functions but I am not successful.

I can not think of a way to achieve this.

Kindly would someone lead me.

Comment: tried `strpos`?

Comment: what's the criteria?

Comment: Will the string always be in the same format? Either `substr` or `preg_replace` will be your best friend.

Comment: @mehulmpt I would want to get the value or amount of recharge. The amount alone. In this case **20** alone ...

Comment: Hi @Jerodev yes, the string format is constant...

Comment: regex `/SH\s+(\d+)\s+to/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try regular expression

```
$str = 'Request to recharge SH 20 to 7567674553 is successful. Balance SH 500';
preg_match_all('/recharge SH ([\d]+)/',$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => recharge SH 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is always the same:

```
$string = strstr("Request to recharge SH ", true);
$pointer = strpos(" ", $string);
$output = substr($string, 0, $pointer);
echo $output;
```